# Linux kernel module - mutex lock necessary here?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, synchronization, kernel-module

Say I implement `dev_write` within my Linux kernel module as so:

```
static ssize_t dev_write(struct file *filep, const char *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *offset)
{
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "buffer[%zu] is '%c'\n", i, buffer[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What happens if two different processes attempt to write to my device simultaneously? Will things execute normally? Do I need to acquire a mutex lock when `dev_open` is invoked, or is that unnecessary in this situation?

Comment: They'll both call your dev_write function at the same time I believe, which will cause the printk output to be intermixed.

Comment: `Will things execute normally?` - It depends on **your meaning** of "normally" (that is, what do you want to achieve). Kernel's core (everything except your driver) would execute normally in any case. Every single line generated by `printk` will be printed without intermixing with lines generated by concurrent calls. If it is OK for you to have lines order like "buffer[0]", "buffer[1]", "buffer[0]" (from the concurrent call), "buffer[2]" ... then no additional synchronization is needed.

Comment: Note, that you have errors not relating with concurrency: 1. `return 0;` will trigger infinite writing by `echo` and other utilities. Instead, use `return len;` 2. `buffer[i]` tries to dereference user-space pointer buffer, which may crash your driver and the kernel core. You should use `copy_from_user` function for extract characters from the `buffer`.